# blueimp plugin uploads multiple files on each subsequent upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I am trying to use the blueimp control to upload only a single file (like a normal HTML file upload). However, after the file has finished uploading, I select a different file, the previous file is uploaded again with the new file.
And subsequently multiple files keep getting uploaded (previously selected files) everytime after I select a file.

Screenshots to illustrate :

[image]

[image]

[image]

How do I solve this problem ?

Here is my javascript initialization code :

```
$().ready(function(){

$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    maxChunkSize:0,
    singleFileUploads: true,
    autoUpload:false,
    progressall: function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        //console.log();
        $('#progress .bar').css(
            'width',
            progress + '%'
        );
    },
    add: function (e, data) {
        $("#start-sql-upload").on('click', function () {
            data.submit();
        });
    }
});
```

});

and my upload form :

```
<form>
    <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files" data-url="http://localhost/database/upload">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="start-sql-upload">Upload File</button>
</form>
```

Please help.

Comment: same problem here. My current workaround is to use send and not add

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and I'm fairly certain that setting the maxNumberOfFiles option resolved this issue. As in:

maxNumberOfFiles: 1

Using your code:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
dataType: 'json',
maxChunkSize:0,
singleFileUploads: true,
autoUpload:false,
maxNumberOfFiles: 1,
progressall: function (e, data) {
    var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
    //console.log();
    $('#progress .bar').css(
        'width',
        progress + '%'
    );
},
add: function (e, data) {
    $("#start-sql-upload").on('click', function () {
        data.submit();
    });
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

remove maxChunkSize:0,

This attribute is to fragment the file size of the parameter passed.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it:

```
add: function (e, data) {
    $("#start-sql-upload").off('click').on('click', function () {
        data.submit();
    });
}
```